# BST insertion function causes weird output (C)

Tags: c, insert, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a program that takes a newline separated list of strings from a file and one by one inserts them into a BST.

The way I have it now results in the tree having all of the node's values be the value of the last string added to the tree.

For example, if the list being inserted is: b a c e d z, an inorder traversal will print the tree as: z z z z z z.

I've traced through this code a large number of times over and can not see what's causing this, i've hit a complete mental block.

Here is the code:

insert.c:

```
#include "node.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void insert_node(Node* root, char *nextString) {
  Node* freshNode;
  freshNode = newNode();
  freshNode->Word = nextString;
  printf("Root->Word = %s\n",root->Word);
  printf("nextString = %s\n",freshNode->Word);
  int newLessThanRoot = 0;
  if (strcmp(root->Word,freshNode->Word) > 0) {
    newLessThanRoot = 1;
  }

  if (newLessThanRoot) {
    if (root->Left == NULL) {
      root->Left = freshNode;
      }
      else {
        insert_node(root->Left, freshNode->Word);
      }
    }
  if (!newLessThanRoot) {
    if (root->Right == NULL) {
      root->Right = freshNode;
    }
    else {
      insert_node(root->Right, freshNode->Word);
    }
  }
}


void inorder(Node *temp) {
  if (temp != NULL) {
    inorder(temp->Left);
    printf("%s ",temp->Word);
    inorder(temp->Right);
  }
}
```

relevant parts of main.c:

```
char inputString[15];
  char *inputStringPtr = &inputString[0];
  Node* root;
  root = newNode();
  fscanf(infile,"%s",inputStringPtr);
  root->Word = inputString;
  printf("Root's word: %s\n",root->Word);

  while (fscanf(infile,"%s",inputStringPtr) == 1) {
      insert_node(root,inputStringPtr);
      printf("%s\n",inputString);
  }

  int numberOfStrings = num_of_strings(root);
  int heightOfBST = height_of_tree(root);
  int numberOfLeaves = num_of_leaves(root);
  inorder(root);
```

Comment: You always insert the same pointer, `inputStrPointer`, which in effect is `inputString`. The contents of hat pointer get overwritten continuously and when you finally print the tree, all nodes have the contents of the last line read. You should therefore store copies of the line in your tree. These copies can either be allocated on the heap or you can use a char array instead of a char pointer as `Word`entry.